# Which port is the High-speed USB 2.0 port on a PowerEdge R900

Tags: dell-poweredge, usb, hardware

I want to connect a relatively low-speed SSD to a PowerEdge R900 because I need something with a decent read/write speed (nothing over 35-40MB/s) and I was having trouble identifying which USB 2.0 port is High-speed USB 2.0. This seemed like something the community should have an answer publicly available for.

Anyone know whether the High-speed USB 2 (480mb/s) is the internal port? I've seen a High-speed USB 2 bus listed in lspci in addition to a regular USB 2 (12mb/s) bus, but I haven't actually found the High-speed USB 2.0 port. Anyone know which port it is?

Comment: Why do you think there is only a single USB 2.0 Port?  Have you tried looking at the manual?  http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/poweredge-r900/research

Comment: I can't really assume that it has only one. I will correct my original question. I have looked at the manual, but it doesn't say anything about Hi-speed USB 2.0 vs regular USB 2.0. All I can say is that the first port I plugged into on the front runs much slower in a speed test.

Comment: The usb 1 port you see in lspci is likely from idrac - all the real ports should be usb 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by @Zoredache your premise is flawed.

All USB 2.0 ports are 480mb/sec and according to [this link](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/poweredge-r900/pd)  all the USB ports are USB 2.0 - including the internal, 2 front and 2 rear ports.

USB 1.x is limited to 12 megs, not USB 2.0 - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.x).

Comment: I must have simply read that wrong. Thank you for your help. My apologies.

Answer (score -1):

On the R320 & R520 The rear ports are faster than the front ports. I was trying to backup a server using a USB connected hard disk and when connected to the front port I could only get 20Mb/s max with a DiskSpd test. When connecting to the rear ports I got a much better 40Mb/s and the Veeam backup was nearly 4 x faster